# QGIS view launching rocket in 3D view

Tags: qgis, rendering, refresh, 3d-view

I have started using QGIS to plot the location of rockets we launch. Apart from the occasional crash, so far it has worked well.

I am new to this so I might have done this the hard way. I have a python code that receives data transmitted from the rocket. The data has time, longitude, latitude, acceleration and altitude. The python code than writes the data to a txt file. I use Spyder python IDE to receive the data and not any QGIS python add-ons (that is a little beyond me for now).

I created a Delaminated text layer that reads the text file and plots markers at the co-ordinates. That layer has a Referesh layer interval of 0.20 seconds.

I created a 3D view to try and get a good perspective of the rockets altitude as it flys. This is where the issue comes in. Due the the text layer refreshing, the 3D view flashes continuously as it tries to render all the layers. Even if i change the refresh rate to 1.0 seconds, it still requires time to unblur the other layers. Is there another way I can have the rockets location markers refresh with causing issues in the 3D view?